# How to find largest file using ls / awk in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I need to display the name and size of the largest file. I found how to display a largest file name: `ls -S | head -1` , but I don't understand how to display file size.

Answer (score 0):

You should not parse `ls` output.

Instead use something like `du -d 1 -a -h | sort -h | tail -2 | head -1`.

To get more information about the capabilities of a program, use `man <command>` or `<command> --help`